# Is it called Desolation Station on purpose?

Tags: star-wars, names, death-star

In the canon *Star Wars* novel *Tarkin*, the rebellious former Republic officer Berch Teller was assigned to the Empire's Desolation Station before going off the grid. It was an Imperial installation that oversaw the research behind the Death Star. They both have the initials DS. Was this on purpose?

Comment: The name came from a non-canon game that was released for the Nintend DS. Despite the tempting comparison, I can't see any reason for the choice of name other than that it was quite far from any inhabited systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlikely. The location first appeared in the 2009 game [Star Wars Battlefront: Elite Squadron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Battlefront:_Elite_Squadron) on the PlayStation Portable and Nintendo DS.

In the game, the Desolation Station was a facility where components for the Death Star were assembled for the Empire before being transported to the Death Star construction site itself. This was later changed to research, specifically of the hyperdrive, after the April 2014 decanonization and the subsequent November 2014 release of the book, *[Tarkin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tarkin_(novel))*.

James Luceno (the author of *Tarkin*) almost certainly got the name and in-universe location from the game. The game designers almost certainly used the name for the "cool factor". And the reason it has anything to do with the Death Star is because that was the only thing of significance in the era the game was set. There is no evidence that the initials were correlated at all.